# What's this type of hairdo called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Offhand, I'd say it's a variation of the bouffant with a bun on top. It transcends generations. Here's a fairly famous painting by John Sloan:

[image]

And, almost a hundred years later, here's Captain Janeway:

[image]

Comment: Or even more. Janeway took command of *Voyager* exactly five hundred years after Sloan was born ([it says here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway))

Comment: How about the [*psyche knot*](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=psyche+knot) from the Edwardian era?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a ***chignon***.

> : a way of arranging a woman's hair by twisting it into a round shape at the back of the head or neck [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chignon)
>
> *"Les Chignons des Années 40 à Aujourd'hui"* [Marie-Claire](http://www.marieclaire.fr/,les-chignon-des-annees-40-a-nos-jours,726262.asp)

Comment: Damn it! I know the word very well, too. Thank you!

Comment: @Ricky You're welcome, Ricky!

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite right: the illustrations show the knot up top rather than at the back or at the nape of the neck, the French for which apparently [gives the *chignon* its name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chignon_%28hairstyle%29). "Nor did she wear a chignon, I'd have you all to know, / And I met her in the garden where the praties grow."

Comment: In French at least, a *chignon* is a *chignon* wherever it is on the head. As a native speaker, I actually had no idea that *chignon* ever meant “back of the neck”. According to the *[Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chignon)*, this meaning is archaic and literary.

Answer (score 6):

It's a **sock bun**.

Because one way of making it is to use a cut sock.

Comment: That's such a cool term!

Comment: It is indeed cool. +1. But a reference would be nice :)

Comment: Instructions for the girls: http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Sock-Bun